# List view permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, security-trimming

We have a PDF file in a SharePoint 2010 Documents library and have created a simple view that shows that one file. We'd like to limit who sees it based on an AD group. From everything on the web, it seems this isn't possible. Can someone provide some clarification on this, if it's possible in a simple way? Thanks.

Comment: Found a workaround: Each item in a list/library can have its permissions set. So the library view now displays all files, but the one file has limited permissions.

Comment: Hi Alex, please make sure you set this as the answer and mark it as so when the timer has shown so this question can be closed off and to help users with this issue in the future.

Comment: Just as a side note though, if you don't need to block access to the document you can use Audiences to filter the views available to users/groups.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in a list/library can have its permissions set. So the library view now displays all files, but the one file has limited permissions.

To do this, simply open the default view of the library, roll over the file until the little dropdown arrow shows. Then click the down arrow and choose `Manage Permissions`. Now add/remove those who should have access to the item; note that this will require breaking inheritance of permissions from the parent (the site) to be able to modify permissions on the file.